# Why does request.security() called for 4H TF return bar_index of 1H bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Please try running this script on 1H timeframe and see (in the data window) that the bar index returned as a field of a user defined type is never a 4H bar index but always a 1H bar_index.
Why?

```
// RUN ON 1H TIMEFRAME
//@version=5
indicator("HTF bar_index",  overlay = true)

type htfData
    int             htfBi

htfF1(htfData _htf) =>
    _htf.htfBi := bar_index
    bar_index

var htfD = htfData.new()

htfBi = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", htfF1(htfD), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)

// turns out that request.security returns 1H bar_index
plotchar(htfBi, "htfBi","", location.belowbar)
plotchar(htfD.htfBi, "htfD.htfBi","", location.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `htfF1()` returns `bar_index`. Therefore, when you pass this function to `request.security()`, it will return the `bar_index` of the 4h timeframe. You can see this by checking out the value of `htfBi` as you did.

Since `_htf.htfBi := bar_index` has no effect on the return value, the values from the current timeframe will be used.

Comment: Looks like that, thank you. It is interesting that if you call request security like this it seems not to execute the ```_htf.htfBi := bar_index``` line at all: 

```htfBi = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", (timeframe.period == "240") ? htfF1(htfD) : na, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)```